# STR_TO_DATE mysql & php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column called `dispatchdate` which is being stores as VARCHAR(255). It is storing dates though as '12/06/2013' format. (DD/MM/YYYY)

I know I should have used a better field, but I am still new/learning with MYSQL & PHP.
It is only on a local PC for testing etc....

On my page, I have a query that does a basic "select * from table" and lists rows.

**I want to redefine the query so that I can enter a date range to narrow down my listings.**

I am currently using...

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('operations');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dispatch");
```

I assume I have to use STR_TO_DATE to convert it from varchar into a date format.
But %d/%m/%Y displays as '2013-06-12' not '12-06-2013'.

How can I build a query in PHP using `SELECT STR_TO_DATE( dispatchdate, '%d/%m/%Y' )` and then enter the criteria to search for (e.g. 01/07/13 -> 31/07/13)

Comment: "I know I should have used a better field, " - absolutely you should. Start by storing your date/time values in a `DATETIME` field.

Comment: Would be grateful if you could expand on that a little, and explain how I can do that...

Comment: When you create your table, specify `DateTime` as the field type instead of `varchar`. Then you can use MySQL's date functions on the date directly, without having to do a conversion first.

Comment: BTW - someone will tell you: PHP's `mysql` functions are deprecated. You shouldn't use them. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Yup, Im aware of that, i'm still reading up on that, and sql injections etc. This is just a local test database. -How do I convert an existing table with lots of data from varchar255 to datetime without loosing it all and starting again?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you want to retrieve it in the character format you are storing.  So, don't do a conversion in the `select`.  Just do a conversion in the `where` clause. For instance, to get rows from the last week:

```
SELECT *
FROM dispatch
where STR_TO_DATE( dispatchdate, '%d/%m/%Y' ) >= adddate(now(),  - 7)
```

Comment: Is that compatible to put that in PHP? I tried that, $result = mysql_query("select * from dispatch where STR_TO_DATE(dispatchdate, '%d/%m/%Y') >= date(now()) - 7 days"); but it gave an error.

Comment: @bnovation . . . The problem was the query.  Using `adddate()` definitely works.

Comment: Thanks when I try that I get Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\dispatch\dispatch-report.php on line 63

Line 63 says:

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dispatchdate'] . "</td>";